# Formatting text coming from Model in MVC form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to add figures together from model and display them formatted like a dollar amount.

Here is the code I'm attempting to format:

```
<td class="confirmationlabel">$@(Model.Amount + Model.FeeAmount) </td>
```

How do I go about formatting the output to be in $0.00 format? I tried adding tostring to the end but it didn't recognize it. Right now, if it is a whole dollar, it comes out without the .00 at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite some parenthesis to get set correctly.
The formats below should do it.

Either call `ToString`

```
$@((Model.Amount + Model.FeeAmount).ToString("0.00"))
```

Or use `string interpolation` (represented by the second `$` here below)

```
$@($"{(Model.Amount + Model.FeeAmount):0.00}")
```

Comment: ty should have thought of that